# Why webpack scss doesnt want to include fonts?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, webpack-style-loader

i have a simple scss file

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
$bootstrap-sass-asset-helper: false !default;
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
$icon-font-name: "glyphicons-halflings-regular" !default;
$icon-font-svg-id: "glyphicons_halflingsregular" !default;
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: $bg;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

And my webpack loader looks like this:

```
  {
    test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 10000,
        mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: 'file-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/client/assets/styles"),
    ],
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: "style-loader",
      use: [
        {
          loader: "css-loader",
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            modules: true,
            importLoaders: 1,
            localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:3]'
          }
        },
        {
          loader: "postcss-loader",
          options: postcssLoaderOptions
        },
        {
          loader: "sass-loader",
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            outputStyle: "compressed"
          }
        }
      ]
    })
  },
```

But i get errors when trying to include my `scss` file

`Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0'`

Changing value for  `modules: true,` helps but i would like to keep it to `true`

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"modules":true,"importLoaders":1,"localIdentName":"[local]_[hash:base64:3]"}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"plugins":[null],"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true,"outputStyle":"compressed"}!./src/client/assets/styles/styles.scss
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0' in
>   '/Users/vardius/Projects/webpack/src/client/assets/styles'
>        @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"modules":true,"importLoaders":1,"localIdentName":"[local]_[hash:base64:3]"}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"plugins":[null],"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true,"outputStyle":"compressed"}!./src/client/assets/styles/styles.scss
>   7:134621-134683

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and I found a solution for this errors.

First I removed the version numbers after the fonts files in the _path.scss in font-awesome scss folder.

```
    src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

And then I added full folder path to `$fa-font-path` variable

```
$fa-font-path : "./assets/vendor/font-awesome/fonts" !default;
```

Hopefully this solves your errors.

Comment: no need to remove the version numbers, just set the `$fa-font-path` variable should do it